# how to stop curl php from sending accept header

Tags: php, curl

By default curl sends `Accept: */*` header for all requests. How do I stop sending of the default header?

```
 Accept: */*
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Pass in "Accept:" (ie a header with no contents to the right of the colon) with [CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html). Like:

```
$headers  =  array( "Accept:" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

The equivalent using the curl command line tool is:

```
curl -H 'Accept:' http://example.com/
```

This will make curl *remove* the header, not just send a header with a blank value. You *can* also send a header with a blank value if you want, but then you need to use a semicolon instead of colon!

Comment: I stumbled across [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130910/how-to-interpret-empty-http-accept-header) prior to reaching this one, and wanted to point out `-H 'Accept:'` does in fact prevent curl from sending the header altogether.  It doesn't send the header as empty as I first thought it would.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your array item is set up with the colon immediately following the header name, like this:

```
array( "Accept: yourAcceptValue" )
```

Not with spaces, like this:

```
array( "Accept : yourAcceptValue" )
```

If there is a space between the header name and the colon, curl will add the default `*/*` into your headers.

(Works in PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7)