# How to interpret empty HTTP Accept header?

Tags: http, http-headers, string

The HTTP/1.1 `Accept` request header is specified in [RFC 2616, section 14.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.1).

It's syntax is given like this:

```
   Accept         = "Accept" ":"
                    #( media-range [ accept-params ] )
```

`#` without any number states *zero or more* according to [section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.1). However, section 14.1 doesn't make any statement about how to interpret an empty `Accept` header. This is in contrast to [section 14.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.2), which talks about `Accept-Encoding`, where not only `1#` is used (*one or more*), but also the case for an empty `Accept-Encoding` header is specified, which is kind of weird. Some other sections dealing with request headers are also specific on the special case of an empty value.

Should one treat an **empty** `Accept` header equivalently to a **non-existent** `Accept` header? Are there any official resources on this I missed?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From [RFC2616 Sec4.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2):

> Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value.

At first glance, this would seem to put messages that specify empty header values in the malformed, non-compliant category. However, the augmented BNF form outlined in [RFC2616 Sec2.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.1) indicates that

> "#element" allows any number, including zero

As this is the declaration used to specify Accept header values, it appears that empty values are valid.

Parsing empty headers and headers with nothing but whitespace can be problematic because of the following direction from the spec:

> The field-content does not include any leading or trailing LWS: linear
>   white space occurring before the first non-whitespace character of the
>   field-value or after the last non-whitespace character of the
>   field-value. Such leading or trailing LWS MAY be removed without
>   changing the semantics of the field value. Any LWS that occurs between
>   field-content MAY be replaced with a single SP before interpreting the
>   field value or forwarding the message downstream.

IMHO, sending an empty header is completely pointless. It shouldn't be done, and parsers may not correctly parse these headers. Traditionally, people who want to circumvent such  limitations when dealing with non-compliant components have specified "pseudo-empty" values like this:

`X-MyCustomHeader: ""`

If you simply want to validate that a header field was sent as some form of boolean switch, consider sending a placeholder value like the above instead of an empty value.

---

**Update**

I guess I wasn't very clear in directly answering the question: in the case of an empty Accept header you really have two options:

- Send a `406 Not Acceptable` response to inform the client that you don't offer any content types for an empty Accept value (duh).

This is justified, but not required by [RFC2616 Sec14.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1):

> If an Accept header field is present, and if the server cannot send a
>   response which is acceptable according to the combined Accept field
>   value, then the server SHOULD send a 406 (not acceptable) response.

- Or, because this is not required and it's highly unlikely the user doesn't accept **any** content-types (otherwise, why would they bother to send the request?) ... I would suggest treating an empty `Accept:` value (if message rejection isn't an option) the same as `Accept: */*`.

Comment: I disagree on empty headers being malformed, especially as the spec itself refers to empty headers (see my Accept-Encoding example). To give context, I'm developing python web middleware and thinking about eventualities and how to test against them. I went for assuming ``*/*``, which seems reasonable to me too. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: I also think that ``400 Bad Request`` would be more appropriate than ``406 Not Acceptable``, at least if we assume that this is a violation of the spec. Cause in that case, we were unable to figure out what the client actually accepts.

Comment: You know, you're right about 2616-2.1 -- the `#element` form does indicate empty header values are okay. I'm going to update my answer to reflect this and avoid misinformation. Also, I think this makes either a 406 response -or- treating it like `Accept: */*` valid. But probably not a 400 since it's not technically an invalid message.

Comment: Whether you go the `406` route or the `*/*` route I think boils down to your preference between correctness and robustness in this case. It seems either is valid as far as the spec is concerned.

Comment: Sorry for the comment-spam. You know what's interesting is that of all the negotiation-type accept headers, `Accept` is the only one specified with `#element`. All the others specifically define `1#element`. I wonder why? It doesn't make much sense to me as the other acceptance headers follow the same format (where q-values and delimiters are concerned). It's interesting, but on the surface it seems like a failure in the spec-design to have this inconsistency. Perhaps I'm wrong, but I don't see what purpose it could serve to allow *0 --> n* `Accept` header definitions.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Maybe it's just a typo which slipped through the reviews. And you're probably right about ``400`` being inappropriate again, because it _is_ ``#`` and not ``1#``…

Comment: this helped me a lot. A very interesting and clean description of the content negotiation in HTTP. Thank You!

Answer (score 7):

According to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2:

> A request without any Accept header field implies that the user agent will accept any media type in response.

You should treat a non-existent `Accept` header as `*/*`.

Comment: True, but you're citing an obsolete specification.

Comment: is the current specification this one: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.1 ?

Comment: No. RFC 2616 has been obsoleted by RFCs 7230 etc.

Comment: The problem is there here the request does have an Accept header field, it just has a blank value.

Comment: Quentin's right, but I got here looking for exactly what cd1 answered.  I'm starting to appreciate related answers even if they aren't directly applicable.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few years since the last answer so here is the current [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231.html#section-5.3.2) which maintains the same advice as previous RFC's:

> A request without any Accept header field implies that the user agent
> will accept any media type in response.