# @GetMapping is called even when Accept is defined how null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am working with Spring Framework `4.3.13.RELEASE`

About **Rest**, for `POST`, I have the following:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/personas")
public class PersonaRestController {

    @PostMapping(consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<Void> saveOne(
            @Validated @RequestBody Persona persona, ...
```

About **Testing** working with `JUnit` and with `ResultActions` I can get the `java.lang.AssertionError: No handler` error message and confirm the following:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /personas
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 415
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Accept=[application/xml, application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Has sense this behaviour because the `saveOne` method expects the content data be either `XML` or `JSON` and for this test scenario the `Content-Type` was not sent.

Therefore is expected that Spring arises a `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException` instance. Then the `@Test` method fails and the `java.lang.AssertionError: No handler` error message appears because there is **no** a handler to handle the user request.

Until here all OK.

Again, about **Rest**, for `GET`, I have the following:

```
@GetMapping(path="/{id}",
            produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody Persona findOneById(@PathVariable String id){
    return personaService.findOneById(id);
}
```

For other **Testing** scenario with the following:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /personas/100
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.manuel.jordan.rest.persona.PersonaRestController
           Method = public com.manuel.jordan.domain.Persona com.manuel.jordan.rest.persona.PersonaRestController.findOneById(java.lang.String)
```

My interceptor shows the following data

```
HttpHeaderControlInterceptor - preHandle 
   HttpServletRequest > 
    URL: http://localhost/personas/100 
    URI: /personas/100 
       HttpMethod: GET 
          Accept: null 
          Accept-Language: null 
          Content-Type: null
```

I am confused why the `findOneById` method was called how a handler even when `Accept` was null. I had expected something similar than the `java.lang.AssertionError: No handler` error message and the [HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.13.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.html) class instead, it because the `findOneById` method can return the data in either `XML` or `JSON`

What is missing?

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully sure but guess that its caused by HTTP 1.1 ,

See Section - **10.4.7 406 Not Acceptable** [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

> Note: HTTP/1.1 servers are allowed to return responses which are
>         not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the
>         request. In some cases, this may even be preferable to sending a
>         406 response. User agents are encouraged to inspect the headers of
>         an incoming response to determine if it is acceptable.

I think, treatment of `consumes` vs `produces` is different and that is why you see the difference.

Refer to this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130910/how-to-interpret-empty-http-accept-header)

I had posted an answer before that I have deleted. Basically, I had misunderstood your question.