# .htaccess: How to check if a request header exists with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-headers

I searched for hours, but it seems Apache has no solution for my need. I need to check if a request header is present and depending on it I want to define a rewrite rule. I can check if the header value is empty, but if the header doesn't exist such condition doesn't consider the existence of the header. I already tried if else directive, but also no success, because Apache seems to have its focus only on the value.

This works if header value is empty but not if these headers don't exist.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Sec-Fetch-Dest} ^$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Sec-Fetch-Mode} ^$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Sec-Fetch-Site} ^$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Sec-Fetch-User} ^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [ENV=TEST:true]
header set x-test "1" env=TEST
```

Comment: This works fine for me, I get `x-test: 1` in the result headers

Comment: Because headers exist. You must test it either with curl or Safari browser on Mac OS.

Comment: I tested using `curl` command: `curl -IL 'localhost/'`

Comment: You are right! I had a syntax error in my curl command.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you cannot differentiate between an HTTP request header that is present but empty or does not exist at all - you would have to assume it does not exist in both cases, which would be the correct action in the majority (all?) of cases. (I'm not aware of any request headers where an *empty* value is considered a *positive* value?)

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Sec-Fetch-Dest} ^$ [NC]
```

The above *condition* will be successful if the `Sec-Fetch-Dest` HTTP request header exists but is empty or is not present at all on the HTTP request.

> This works if header value is empty but not if these headers don't exist.
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Sec-Fetch-Dest} ^$ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Sec-Fetch-Mode} ^$ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Sec-Fetch-Site} ^$ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Sec-Fetch-User} ^$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^.*$ - [ENV=TEST:true]
> header set x-test "1" env=TEST
> ```

I'm not sure why you state that this does not work if the headers "don't exist". This should be processed the same whether all the headers don't exist or are all empty, which is arguably the correct action.

None of these headers permit an *empty* value, so assuming they don't exist when they are empty is certainly the correct action in this case.

Further reading:

- [How to interpret empty HTTP Accept header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130910/how-to-interpret-empty-http-accept-header)

Comment: These headers are unsupported with Safari browser, so they don't exist, because not set and that's why this doesn't work.

Comment: If the headers don't exist then the rule is successful (the env var `TEST` is set and ultimately the `x-test` response header is set), exactly the same as when the headers are present but empty. _Aside:_ Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file that triggers a rewrite loop? In that case, the env var `TEST` is renamed to `REDIRECT_TEST` and the response header will not be set (but this is an unrelated issue). @Serpentdriver

Comment: Read my comment above. Issue is solved!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments above that your shown code should work *as is* to set request header `x-test` for both the cases i.e.

1. All the four mentioned headers are empty
2. All the four mentioned headers are missing (you wanted this one to work)

I am suggesting a more concise code using [`mod_setenvif`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html)

```bash
SetEnvIf ^Sec-Fetch-(Dest|Mode|Site|User)$ ^$ aTEST
Header set x-test "1" env=aTEST
```

Note how we can combine all four headers in single regular expression instead of 4 different `RewriteCond` directives in your shown `mod_rewrite` rule.

---

For testing I have used following `curl` commands on my locally running Apache:

```bash
curl -IL -H 'localhost/'
curl -IL -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: foo' 'localhost/'
curl -IL -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: bar' 'localhost/'
```

We will get `x-test: 1` shown in response only for the first command.