# Send a curl request with no Accept header?

Tags: http, rest, curl

I have written an REST API and I'm try to test a request that has no Accept header. If I send a request via Curl it adds a default header `Accept: */*`, you can see this if you add Curl's -v parameter.

Is there are way to send a request via Curl with no Accept header?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638661/how-to-stop-curl-php-from-sending-accept-header. Just pass a blank `Accept` header as follow: `curl -H 'Accept:' http://example.com/`.

Answer (score 29):

Pass in a header with no value on the right side of the colon to have that removed from the request, even if curl otherwise would add it by itself.

```
curl -H 'Accept:' http://example.com/
```