# How to remove Accept from the http header in libcurl

Tags: c++, c, http, curl, libcurl

Libcurl is putting Accept on the http header with the default value `Accept: */*`.

I want to avoid libcurl putting Accept in the http header. How I can do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638661/how-to-stop-curl-php-from-sending-accept-header (not C, but still)

Comment: As @deviantfan says, the exact same way applies for libcurl in C.

Comment: @DanielStenberg the example is in php, And I can not find the equivalent of this code in C. could you please provide the equivalent of this code in C in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set a header with no "contents" on the right of the colon to remove it from libcurl's request (see the [CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html) docs):

```
struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Accept:");

res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

For a slightly more complete example in C using custom headers, see [httpcustomheader.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/httpcustomheader.html)